# Keras Error - expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 1)?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, vgg-net

i am trying to use VGG16 pretrained in Keras, but i keep getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 1)

What is the error mean?

> Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (6, 1)

This the my actual code:

```
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = 'database/train'
validation_data_dir = 'database/validation'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 26
epochs = 50
batch_size = 20

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
print('VGG-16 Model loaded.')

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=input_shape))
top_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))

top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
top_model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
top_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
top_model.add(Flatten())

top_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(12))
top_model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
# classifier, including the top classifier,
# in order to successfully do fine-tuning
# top_model.load_weights('./vgg16_face_weights.h5')

# add the model on top of the convolutional base
model.add_update(top_model)

# set the first 25 layers (up to the last conv block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

The terminal run:

```
VGG-16 Model loaded.
Found 46 images belonging to 12 classes.
Found 26 images belonging to 12 classes.
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/w024029h/PycharmProjects/keras_pretrained/pretrained.py", line 113, in <module>
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\w024029h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\w024029h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2230, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\w024029h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1877, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\w024029h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1480, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\w024029h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 1)
```

Comment: The error is raising by input images dims, can you add dims of input images by manually reading? I have tested your model, there is no problem.

Comment: how much i should raise the input dimension? on my image database the image has various of dimension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same error before. I resolved it by changing the class_mode on the data generators from 'binary' to None

According to the keras docs, setting the class_mode to 'binary' will return a 1-D array.

By changing the class_mode=None, no labels are returned and the generator will only yield batches of image data. This is what you are expecting with your model and this works well with the fit_generator() method. However, when using class_mode None, the data still needs to reside in a subdirectory of directory for it to work correctly.

[This page was useful to me](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

^look at flow_from_directory()

Hope this helps!